# Unable to mock the custom object addEventListener(e)

Tags: jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme, addeventlistener

Hi I'm facing issue in mocking the custom created object addEventListener.
Below is my react render code

```
<Fragment>
            <div
                className={`${Styles.resizable} resizable`}
                ref={resizableRef}
                style={{ width: width, height: height }}
            >
                <div className={`${Styles.resizable_resizers} resizers`}>
                    <div
                        className={`${Styles.resizable_resizers_resizer} ${Styles[resizeDirection]} resizer ${resizeDirection}`}
                    ></div>
                    {children}
                </div>
                {maxCharacter !== null ? (
                    <div className={`${Styles.resizable__limit}`}>
                        {characterCount} / {maxCharacter}
                    </div>
                ) : null}
            </div>
        </Fragment>
```

Using the useLayoutEffect in React hook - i'm manipulating the DOM

```
        const resizers = resizableRef.current.querySelectorAll(".resizable .resizer");
        for (let i = 0; i < resizers.length; i++) {
            const currentResizer = resizers[i];

            const resize = (e) => {
                if (currentResizer.classList.contains("bottomright")) {
                    resizableRef.current["style"].width =
                        e.pageX - resizableRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().left + "px";
                    resizableRef.current["style"].height =
                        e.pageY - resizableRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().top + "px";
                } else if (currentResizer.classList.contains("vertical")) {
                    resizableRef.current["style"].height =
                        e.pageY - resizableRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().top + "px";
                } else if (currentResizer.classList.contains("horizontal")) {
                    resizableRef.current["style"].width =
                        e.pageX - resizableRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().left + "px";
                }
            };

            const stopResize = () => {
                window.removeEventListener("mousemove", resize);
            };

            currentResizer.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                window.addEventListener("mousemove", resize);
                window.addEventListener("mouseup", stopResize);
            });
        }
    }, []);
```

I was writing unit test case for above code, but seems that **currentResizer.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {....});** is not getting mocked and i'm not able to further proceed.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How are you mocking it? Share the jest code also

Comment: Hi, please find the link, i tried with multiple scenario to mock it -- https://codepen.io/ruchiprsd/pen/dyGKQgK

Answer (score 0):

You should be mocking the `resize` and `stopResize` instead of `currentResizer`.
Reasons:

- You should not test the implementation details, but focus on the functionality. If you test your implementation, the moment you change code your tests break. But if you are testing functionality, it will not break.
- Technically mocking methods and properties of a functional component is not yet available in enzyme and jest. For class components we can use it `wrapper.instance().method=jest.fn()` . But we cannot do this in functional components.

One solution for your problem is to modify your component code to accept the `resize` and `stopResize` methods as props. And then mock them in the test. Check whether they are getting called on mousemove and mouseup

Comment: Thanks for information, I tried achieving through dispatchEvent(). And its covering the test case.